# IIS 8 and MSMQ over HTTP without WCF

Tags: iis, http, msmq

I am trying to config a new **Server 2012 R2** server running **IIS 8** and **MSMQ**. I have create a **private queue** and trying to send it messages over **HTTP** from a server in another domain. I have granted the **Everyone** group **Full** permissions and using **Wireshark**, I see the packets coming over HTTP.

Yet nothing shows up in the queue itself. I have searched high and low but have found nothing to suggest the problem. The vast majority of articles out there are for when WCF is in the picture.

The only areas I think could be causing a problem are

- Permissions -- think this is covered via the Everyone group having full permissions
- IIS website bindings -- for example net.msmq but I do not think I need this because my understanding is that this is needed for WCF which is not in play here
- Queue naming -- Everything I read says I am referencing this correctly
- Missing role or feature -- I cannot find any definitive list of what I need when WCF is not used. (For example, I have HTTP Support installed for MSMQ but do not have any of the WCF Services features like HTTP Activation since I am not using WCF.)
- IIS Handlers -- I know when dealing with WCF you need to "fix" *.svc in MIME Types section but as far as I know there is no extension in play here.

For info purposes, here are the relevant names and references

- Queue name: **apps-02\private$\solr_incidents**
- Sending Reference: **`DIRECT=HTTP://apps-02/msmq/private$/solr_incidents`** (I have tried using the ip address too instead of host name.)
- Wireshark:

  ```
        POST /msmq/private$/solr_incidents HTTP/1.1

        http://apps-02/msmq/private$/solr_incidents

        Returns HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  ```

Is there anything else I can look at? Are there are blogs or articles providing specific settings/requirements for MSMQ over HTTP **without** adding all the pieces for WCF?

Comment: Could you correct the "Sending Reference" please?

Comment: John -- Thank you for that. For some odd reason, it was rendering differently than actually typed. I had to mark that as "code" in order for the proper value to be displayed. (Although preview does/did render properly.) Does SO do something special with text that has HTTP in it?

Comment: Switch on IIS logging to see what happens. May just match the Wireshark data but could provide some insight. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/10/21/troubleshooting-msmq-over-http-nothing-in-the-web-server-log-files.aspx

Comment: You've given "Everyone" access but that's not everyone. "Anonymous Logon" needs to be added to really cover everyone.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell -- That was it. Needed Anonymous Logon...cannot believe I missed that one. Would have thought there would be some sort of permission denied message someplace but maybe not. Please move your comment to an answer so I can mark it. Thank you.

Comment: Negative source journaling may have provided the 'access denied' information.

Comment: Never heard of Negative source journaling. Will have to look into that. Thank you John.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739818(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've given "Everyone" access but that's not everyone.

"Anonymous Logon" needs to be added to really cover everyone.